# Plot sheet Depending on the cell Value (YES, NO)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a cell in an Excel spreadsheet in which you can select yes/no in Sheet 1. If the option yes is selected I want that row to be pasted in the Sheet2 in the same format.

Should I use a button or can a simple formula do it?

Comment: To copy and paste you need a macro.  Try recording a macro and then editing it to suit your needs.  Post the code if you run into problems.

Comment: Use Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
'write the code to copy the row data
End Sub